# Como tomar el nombre de los elementos de una carpeta de forma ordenada JFileChooser

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un programa el cual pueda elegir una carpeta con JFileChooser y que en consola muestre el nombre de los archivos de la carpeta de forma ordenada.

```
JFileChooser selecto = (JFileChooser) e.getSource();
    String comand = e.getActionCommand();
    if (comand.equals(JFileChooser.APPROVE_SELECTION)) {

        File rutaActual = selecto.getSelectedFile();
        File[] archivos = rutaActual.listFiles();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Archivos de la carpeta "+rutaActual.getName()+" renombrados exitosamente ");

        String nombreCarpeta = rutaActual.getName();
        this.transformar = new Transformador();

        for (int i = 0; i < archivos.length; i++) {


            System.out.println(archivos[i].getName()+"\n");
        }

    }
```

Pero resulta que aparece in-concorde en ciertos casos, como por ejemplo elegir una carpeta que contenga  12 archivos con los nombres de cada archivo, igual al lugar que corresponda, esto muestra por pantalla: ( 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ) de esa manera no se que podría arreglar en mi código para solucionar mi problema.

Cualquier ayuda será bien recibida.

Answer (score 0):

Para eso tienes que ordenar la lista. Primero tienes que convertir el Array en List para poder ordenarla, para convertir un Array a List utiliza le metodo asList() de la clase Arrays. Despues utilizas el metodo sort() de la clase Collections para ordenar la lista.

Convierte el Array a List.

```
List<File> listaArchivos = Arrays.asList(archivos);
```

Ordena la lista utilizando los nombres de los archivos.

```
Collections.sort(listaArchivos, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
```

Imprime la lista

```
for (File archivo : listaArchivos) {
    System.out.println(archivo.getName());
}
```

---

Al final el codigo se veria asi:

```
...

if (...) {

    File rutaActual = selecto.getSelectedFile();
    File[] archivos = rutaActual.listFiles();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Archivos de la carpeta "+rutaActual.getName()+" renombrados exitosamente ");

    String nombreCarpeta = rutaActual.getName();
    this.transformar = new Transformador();

    List<File> listaArchivos = Arrays.asList(archivos);

    Collections.sort(listaArchivos, new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
            return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
        }
    });

    for (File archivo : listaArchivos) {
        System.out.println(archivo.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Buena respuesta pero esto no es cierto "Primero tienes que convertir el Array en List para poder ordenarla". Un ArrayList lo puedes ordenar (manualmente), aunque con una lista es más sencillo y rápido.

Comment: Intente usar el metodo sugerido pero resulta que el metodo para transformar de array a List no me funciono y me manda un error            
 type list does not take parameters intente usar el metodo ArrayList<File> listaArchivos = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(archivos)); pero tampoco solucionó mi problema

Comment: Lo solucione era un error de librerias, pero de todos modos el codigo sugerido no soluciono mi problema y me sigue arrojando 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9

Comment: cual de las dos estas importando? java.awt.List ó java.util.List

Comment: ahora no tengo ningún error con java.util.List pero mi problema aun no lo tengo resuelto